# Why my property does not exist on type 'never'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

I'm trying to type a ts file which is for some slices in react js using redux. The problem is that I keep having this error : "Property 'quantity' does not exist on type 'never'.".

Here's the code :

```
addToCart: (state, action) => {
        const itemInCart = state.cart.find(
            (item: Record<string, unknown>) => item.id === action.payload.id
        )
        if (itemInCart) {
            itemInCart.quantity++
        } else {
            state.cart.push({ ...action.payload, quantity: 1 })
        }
    },
```

I tried to add the Record<string, unknown> type but this doesn't make any changes. Do you have any suggestions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By typing `item` as `Record<string, unknown>` you're typing any property of item to be unknown. This means item.id and itemInCart.quantity are both unknown types. You can not increment an unknown type.

**Quick fix**
If you don't mind switching to type-less code, you can change `Record<string, unknown>` to `Record<string, any>` and it would work.
Or if that doesn't work you can try changing `const itemInCart` to `const itemInCart: any`.

**Better fix**
Create a type or interface for items in your cart. E.g:

```
interface CartItem {
   id: string;
   quentity: number;
}
```

(I'm assuming here that id is a string, you can change it to whatever is the actual type)
And then use `Record<string, CartItem>`

Answer (score 0):

Try writing it like this:

```js
const [arr, setArr] = useState<any[]>([])
```

Comment: I would like to avoid using any